# listview not firing onitemclicklistener with if

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have an application, displaying a bookmark deriving from various table. The bookmark activity has a listview with two textviews. The first textview is used to display the list of words and the second textview is to display the name of a table from which the word is deriving. What I want is that, when I click on an item, it will go the an activity based on the name of the table displayed in the second textview. But, so far it does want to fire up or create an error. Here is my code:

```
lview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            tview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.MPList);
            String text1 = tview.getText().toString();
            dictview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.BMPDictList);
            String text2 = dictview.getText().toString();
            if (text2.equals("tblA")){
                Intent inten = new Intent(Page.this, ActTblA.class);
                inten.putExtra("wordlist", text1);
                startActivity(inten);
            } else if (text2.equals("tblB")){
                Intent inten = new Intent(Page.this, ActTblB.class);
                inten.putExtra("wordlist", text1);
                startActivity(inten);
            }


        }});
```

If I use the above code, it does not fire up. But if I unbind the tview2 to the view (just simply `dictview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.BMPDictList);`) it will create an error. Can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt with your **OnItemClickListener**, Use `AdapterView's onItemClickListener` like,

```
lview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      // Your code
   } 
});
```